# Binary Numeric Promotion for Floats

Tags: java, type-promotion

In the JLS in 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, **if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.**
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

This confuses me because both
[http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html) and
https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-int-double-float-mixed-type-division-arithmetic-rules

state that

> All floating point values (float and double) in an arithmetic operation (+, −, *, /) are converted to double type before the arithmetic operation in performed.

With my understanding, according to the JLS, adding 1 float and 1 integer would result in a float. However, according to the other sources, adding 1 float and 1 integer would result in a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a source makes a claim contrary to the JLS, chances are good that it's wrong. In this case, the following demonstrates the behaviour that the JLS describes:

```
    Number n = 1 + 0.1f;
    System.out.println(n instanceof Float); // true
    System.out.println(n instanceof Double); // false
```